# React native crypto module issue

Tags: react-native

I created my app with `expo init`

and I'm trying to implement `web3`,I followed every instruction i've found on github but I'm still getting error

```
While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file `/home/user/Desktop/Wallet/Fanbase-Wallet-App/node_modules/bignumber.js/bignumber.js`, the package `/home/user/Desktop/Wallet/Fanbase-Wallet-App/node_modules/crypto/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/home/user/Desktop/Wallet/Fanbase-Wallet-App/node_modules/crypto/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

I have crypto in my `package.json` like this

```
"crypto": "react-native-crypto",
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you update the question with error message you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use expo version of the `crypto` module.

```
expo install expo-crypto
```

more information is available here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/

For web3 there are other implementations in expo. Here is one for CRNA app. But comments include more details on to make it work on expo. https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/29e60920d8fa1982535247563eb63766

Comment: Will it be better if i implement web3 from server? because i cant make it work on rn no matter what guide i follow

Comment: nearly 2.5 years later and we are all still struggling to get any form of crypto libraries working inside react-native -- whats going on?